# Why I don't get any error (C-style casting)

Tags: c++, casting, stack, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
char c{ 10 };
int* i = (int*)&c;
*i = 1; // Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'c' was corrupted.
```

But I don't get any error in this case

```
char* c = new char{ 10 };
int* i = (int*)&c;
*i = 1;
//delete c;
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Do note that not getting an error does not mean it is correct, merely that the compiler did not detect the issue (what you do there is clearly not allowed before C++20).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
int* i = (int*)&c;
```

you make `i` point to the variable `c` itself, not where `c` is actually pointing.

Thus `*i = 1` will change the value of the pointer variable `c` not the value of `*c`.

If you want to get the same (or similar) behavior you should make `i` point to where `c` is pointing:

```
int* i = (int*) c;
```

---

As for why it doesn't give you any error, it's because on modern system `int` is 32 bits wide, while a pointer (like `c`) will be *at least* 32 bits wide as well (and 64 bits on a 64-bit system).

---

Lastly a note about doing C-style casts in C++: You should always take it as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Just to be clear, your the latest cast could not cause error too in some cases, if you don't enable address sanitisers. Memory in heap is allocated by chunks which could exceeed requested size, so `int* i = (int*)c` could still point to some "valid" (for OS) memory so you even won't get "Segmentation fault", if you're "lucky" enough.

Comment: Some programmer dude, Pavel.Zh thank you all for your explanations!